# magento https error

Tags: magento

when i made https enabled in secure url and front end secure url usage to yes in magento the checkout page becomes not found. Should i need to do anything more? where i have to place my ssl certificates.

please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your web server (presumably apache?) and point it to your ssl certificate. You also need to make sure that mod_ssl is enabled. The config files will be in /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd depending on the OS. You should find the ssl.conf file and set the location of the certificate there. To enable mod_ssl you can issue the following command in the command line:

```
a2enmod ssl
```